# Disable replacing forward slashes to one slash in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a GET method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/**")
public ResponseEntity<String> getGraph(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String name = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
```

and the request has multiple forms like:

1. www.test.com/abc//def
2. www.test.com/abc/def
3. www.test.com/abc/def/ghi

it works fine in cases 2&3
but in case 1 name's value is abc/def not abc//def
its replaces the forward slashes to one slash

how i can make it works?

Comment: Can you try with this **@RequestMapping(value = { "/{varName:.+}" })**
[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex)

Comment: This is the desired behavior. Usually web servers are combining double slashes to one slash

Comment: @Govind thanks a lot for your help, but it doesn't worked with me

Comment: @Eklavya thanks a lot for this link, you saved my life, the second answer worked with me

Comment: Then close the question.